# Rails gem sources is shows nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-gnome2

Rails gem sources shows nothing. when i try to add rubygems to gem sources it shows following error.
    `$ gem sources -a https://rubygems.org`

```
    Error fetching https://rubygems.org:
    timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

How do i add rubygems to gem sources.

Comment: try `gem install bundler` then 'bundle install'

Comment: You have an issue with SSL handshake. Use `gem sources -a http://rubygems.org`.

Comment: @Vishal,  gem install bundler throws error: Could not find a valid gem 'bundler; in any repository.

Comment: @mudasobwa, still same error i'm getting

Comment: Then it means _rubygems.org_ is kinda down. Wait and retry.

Comment: try `wget https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz` to see if the file is accessible at all. It is for me.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with SSL if it's not an issue with your internet or rubygems.com being down.

If you're using RVM:

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

Without RVM you can try...

```
gem install bundler
```

or

```
gem update --system
```

See also: http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/

Answer (score -1):

I changed  ~/.gemrc

```
---
:backtrace: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources: []
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
```

to

```
---
:backtrace: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources: ["http://rubygems.org"]
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
```

it worked for me.
Thanks

Comment: Adding the non-https URLs to rubygems opens you up to a lot of potentially bad issues, including the possibility for an adversary to change gems during transport and to e.g. include malicious code, snooping which gems you install, ... You should fix your ability to to fetch gems over https instead. Possibly by configuring your firewall, a required proxy or anything else.

Comment: @HolgerJust How to install gems behind firewall. my firewall is blocking gem installations. is there any other way to install gem even though firewall is blocking..?

Comment: You can manually download gems from https://rubygems.org but it won't be very convenient to install all the gems manually. Instead, you could configure an HTTPS proxy for rubygems if required. Or you can reconfigure your firewall. Check this with your IT team.

Comment: @HolgerJust  gem install -p http://proxy_ip:proxy_port gem_name command worked for me.